# How to handle Restangular .getList() response that's not an array

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The API I'm working with returns 200 with a string error message when the client isn't authenticated. So if I call:

```
var restSvc = Restangular.service('message');
var deferred = restSvc.getList()
```

when authenticated I get back an array of objects -- but if I call it when not authenticated I get back the string "The caller could not be authenticated."

The problem is I'm not able to handle this error because Restangular throws an error and doesn't resolve or fail the deferred because it's expecting an array:

```
Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
```

How can I handle this error and get the response even if it's not an array?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to add a response interceptor to test the data before it is returned. If it conforms to a specific format then attach that to response data. For example.

```
restangularConfig.addResponseInterceptor(function(response, operation) {
    if (operation === 'getList') {
        // Test your data structure here.
    }
    return response;
});
```

If this is your own API you are designing I would highly recommend changing the format to be consistent with every request. For example.

If the request is good.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "content": [{},{}...]  
}
```

If the request is bad.

```
{
  "status": 401, //or what ever error
  "content": []
}
```